# DetailDisclosure button not showing in annotation view

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

For some odd reason the detail button somehow stopped appearing:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
MKPinAnnotationView *pinAnnotation = nil;
if(annotation != mapView.userLocation) 
{
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinAnnotation = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"sadasdasd"];
    if ( pinAnnotation == nil ){
        pinAnnotation = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"sadasdasd"] autorelease];

        /* add detail button */
        NSLog(@"Here");

        UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        pinAnnotation.rightCalloutAccessoryView = infoButton;


    }

}

return pinAnnotation;
}
```

Here is output.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First problem is that `pinAnnotation` is declared twice in that method.

Once in the first line and second in the `if(annotation != mapView.userLocation)...` block.  Because of this, the `return` statement returns `nil` because the outer variable is never set (resulting in a default `MKAnnotationView` callout with no accessory).

Change the second declaration to just an assignment.

Next problem is that you need to set `canShowCallout` to `YES` because the default is `NO` for an `MKPinAnnotationView`.  You can do this after setting the accessory view:

```
pinAnnotation.canShowCallout = YES;
```

The above should fix the accessory button not showing.

Unrelated, but you also need to set the view's `annotation` property when it is being re-used (in the case when it is not nil after the dequeue).  So add an `else` block to the `if (pinAnnotation == nil)`:

```
else {
    //annotation view being re-used, set annotation to current...
    pinAnnotation.annotation = annotation;
}
```