# When to link annotation property in viewForAnnotation method

Tags: ios, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I came across this piece of code in Apple's [Location and Maps Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH6-SW47):

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView
                      viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    // If the annotation is the user location, just return nil.
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    // Handle any custom annotations.
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MyCustomAnnotation class]])
    {
        // Try to dequeue an existing pin view first.
        MKPinAnnotationView*    pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView*)[mapView
        dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"CustomPinAnnotationView"];

        if (!pinView)
        {
            // If an existing pin view was not available, create one.
            pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                       reuseIdentifier:@"CustomPinAnnotationView"];
            pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
            pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
            pinView.canShowCallout = YES;

            // If appropriate, customize the callout by adding accessory views (code not shown).
        }
        else
            pinView.annotation = annotation;

        return pinView;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

I have a question regarding this part:

```
else
    pinView.annotation = annotation;
```

I saw the same code in a Stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7665737/3947107):

> Unrelated, but you also need to set the view's `annotation` property
>   when it is being re-used (in the case when it is not nil after the
>   dequeue).  So add an `else` block to the `if (pinAnnotation == nil)`:
>
> ```
> else {
>     //annotation view being re-used, set annotation to current...
>     pinAnnotation.annotation = annotation;
> }
> ```

Why is the annotation property set in the else block? Shouldn't the annotation be set regardless if a view was reused or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initialise the `MKPinAnnotationView` with the annotation so the else is just so you won't set it twice. It is perfectly fine to set it twice but of course inefficient.

Comment: Oh my, I completely missed that!